# C# CsQuery парсинг

Tags: c#, jquery, парсер

В общем, проблема такая. Надо распарсить HTML код и достать из него Description, Keywords и другие теги. Все тэги парсятся и записываются в переменную tg отлично, а вот Description не хочет. Вот просто возвращает null.

Детали:

1. В кейс Description заходит и код выполняется
2. continue не при чём, так как на моменте выполнения, отслеживал дебагером и переменная не заполняется.
3. (САМОЕ СТРАННОЕ) Пишу `dom["meta[name=description]"]` в Watch 1 (Watch Window) где можно посмотреть значение переменных на момент выполнения программы, иии всё работает, код возвращает весь тэг `<meta name="Description" content="...">`

Код:

```
            CQ dom = text;
            CQ tg;

            switch (tags[i])
            {
                case "Description":
                       tg = dom["meta[name=description]"];   //Тут ничего не записывается
                    continue;
                default:
                       tg = dom[tags[i]];  //тут всё отлично записывается  tags[i] = "h2";
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: Думаю, дело как раз в `continue` - этот оператор начинает новую итерацию цикла, поэтому всё, что после `switch`, не выполнится. А именно там, по идее, обработка полученного значения `tg`.

Comment: В общем проблема смешная, у меня в коде, который я парсил был не "description", a "Description". Правда тогда странно, почему watcher нормально отреагировал на другой регистр.